# Should we be using git submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

How handy would `git submodule` come into a collaborating project? If I have a project that contains multiple separate works in different repositories, it sounds logical to use submodule. However, I have read there are certain drawbacks, including how difficult it is when it comes to merging.

So can anyone who has experience using submodule please give me some feedbacks?

Many thanks,

Comment: I will not post this as an answer as I'm not an expert on submodules nor subtrees, but the following articles could prove to be useful when deciding about submodules: https://medium.com/@porteneuve/mastering-git-submodules-34c65e940407 and https://medium.com/@porteneuve/mastering-git-subtrees-943d29a798ec They're a bit dated but contains loads of relevant information.

Comment: From what I have read on the articles, they do look like a lot of effort to set it up correctly and then a lot of extra effort to make sure all manual works are done correctly from individuals as well......

Comment: https://medium.com/@dopeddude/git-submodule-with-git-hooks-for-scalable-repos-50924f969937